# Connect Overlapping Faces/Verticles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, edit-mode, edges, faces

[image]

Hello!

I have problem to connect this column to the base like in the photo.
I would like to connect that parts as one connected edges.
Please help :(

Comment: Maybe have a look at the answer here (summary: use loop cuts and merge the double vertices) https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/146673/correcting-non-manifold-edges-in-blender-3d-model-for-3d-print?noredirect=1#comment250505_146673 (The quickest way to model something like this would be to do two loopcuts and then extrude the upper face to make that column)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't know a lot about your topology, but you could try this way: Select your top cube, then click *Face* > *Intersect (Boolean)*, then change the Operator box setting to *Union*. You may need to make some adjustments like *Remove Doubles* (*Merge by Distance* in 2.8) or draw some edges with knife (or J to join vertices).

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Thats work!